# Access query fails to find time difference

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to execute the follwoing query in Access 2000 db but I always get #ERROR in the Diff field. Please help me to fix it.

```
PARAMETERS [Enter Date] DateTime;
SELECT sub.Emp_ID, sub.Name, Dept, sub.Day, sub.Attending, sub.Leaving, sub.Leaving -         sub.Attending AS Diff
FROM [SELECT
        M.EmpID AS Emp_ID,M.Name,M.Dept,
IIf (IsNull(H.EventDate), "NP", H.EventDate) AS [Day],
        MIN(H.EventTime) AS Attending,
        MAX(H.EventTime) AS Leaving
    FROM
        Member AS M
        LEFT JOIN History AS H
        ON
            (M.UserID = H.EventUserID 
        AND Format([EventDate], "dd/mm/yyyy") = [Enter Date])
    WHERE
        M.EmpID NOT IN (select EmpID from exceptionList)
    GROUP BY
        M.EmpID, M.Name, M.Department,EventDate
]. AS sub
ORDER BY sub.Emp_ID;
```

Comment: Does subquery return something? Because Format([EventDate], "dd/mm/yyyy") = [Enter Date]) is a rather strange condition when datetime is converted to string and compared to datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace

```
   ON
             (M.UserID = H.EventUserID 
         AND Format([EventDate], "dd/mm/yyyy") = [Enter Date])
     WHERE
```

with

```
  ON
            ((M.UserID = H.EventUserID) 
        AND ([EventDate]= [Enter Date]))
    WHERE
```

Comment: Still the result is same.

Comment: may be this will help:     nz(sub.Leaving,0) - nz(sub.Attending,0) AS Diff